# TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Tags: python

In the example, I was told to use `urllib.request.urlopen`. However, with Python 3.7 in PyCharm urllib package is not available only urllib3. It does not have urlopen. So, I switched to the `requests` package. Now, I get the error in the subject line.

Here is my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, site):
        self.site = site
        self.links = []

    def get_links(self, number_of_pages):
        for i in range(1, number_of_pages):
            response = requests.get(self.site + str(i))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
            for a in soup.find_all("a", href=True):
                print(a['href'])


scraper = Scraper('https://www.celebritynetworth.com/category/richest-celebrities/page/')
scraper.get_links(10)
```

Comment: You need to get the text out of the response for BS to parse it; read the requests docs to see how.

Comment: are you looking to get the `href` of the celebrities only ? or all ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for item in range(1, 11):
    r = requests.get(
        f"https://www.celebritynetworth.com/category/richest-celebrities/page/{item}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    for item in soup.findAll('h3', {'class': 'title'}):
        for tag in item.findAll("a"):
            print("Name: {:<30}, Url: {:>}".format(tag.text, tag.get("href")))
```

Output:

```
Name: Chris Jansing Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/authors/chris-jansing-net-worth/
Name: AJ Rafael Net Worth           , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/aj-rafael-net-worth/
Name: Rodney Kendrick Net Worth     , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/rock-stars/rodney-kendrick-net-worth/
Name: Mark Patton Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/mark-patton-net-worth/
Name: Dream Doll Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-rappers/dream-doll-net-worth/
Name: Anne Hearst Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/authors/anne-hearst-net-worth/
Name: Tyler Shaw Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/tyler-shaw-net-worth/
Name: Riley Smith Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/riley-smith-net-worth/
Name: Roman Griffin Davis Net Worth , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/roman-griffin-davis-net-worth/
Name: Cynthia Erivo Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/cynthia-erivo-net-worth/
Name: Fredo Santana Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-rappers/fredo-santana-net-worth/
Name: David Leisure Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/david-leisure-net-worth/
Name: Ty England Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/ty-england-net-worth/
Name: Normani Kordei Net Worth      , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/normani-kordei-net-worth/
Name: Ramy Youssef Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-comedians/ramy-youssef-net-worth/
Name: Don Imus Net Worth            , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/don-imus-net-worth/
Name: Cardi B Net Worth             , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/models/cardi-b-net-worth/
Name: Kylie Jenner Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/models/kylie-jenner-net-worth/
Name: Eddie Murphy Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/eddie-murphy-net-worth/
Name: Harrison Ford Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/harrison-ford-net-worth/
Name: Henry Cavill Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/henry-cavill-net-worth/
Name: Billie Eilish Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/billie-eilish-net-worth/
Name: PewDiePie Net Worth           , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/pewdiepie-net-worth/
Name: Jim Carrey Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/jim-carrey-net-worth/
Name: Leonardo DiCaprio Net Worth   , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/leonardo-dicaprio-net-worth/
Name: Christopher Abbott Net Worth  , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/christopher-abbott-net-worth/
Name: Jodie Comer Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/jodie-comer-net-worth/
Name: Tobias Menzies Net Worth      , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/tobias-menzies-net-worth/
Name: Lisa Ann Net Worth            , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/models/lisa-ann-net-worth/
Name: Christy Canyon Net Worth      , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/models/christy-canyon-net-worth/
Name: Gerardo Ortiz Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/gerardo-ortiz-net-worth/
Name: Big Sean Net Worth            , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-rappers/big-sean-net-worth/
Name: Scott Galloway Net Worth      , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/authors/scott-galloway-net-worth/
Name: Jack Nicholson Net Worth      , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/jack-nicholson-net-worth/
Name: Mike Ward Net Worth           , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-comedians/mike-ward-net-worth/
Name: Bobby Deol Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/bobby-deol-net-worth/
Name: Chris White Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/rock-stars/chris-white-net-worth/
Name: Dude Perfect Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/directors/dan-dude-net-worth/
Name: Brie Larson Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/brie-larson-net-worth/
Name: Jami Gertz Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/jami-gertz-net-worth/
Name: Trixie Mattel Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/trixie-mattel-net-worth/
Name: Hannah Brown Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/models/hannah-brown-net-worth/
Name: Frankie Muniz Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/frankie-muniz-net-worth/
Name: Juice Wrld Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-rappers/juice-wrld-net-worth/
Name: Don Imus Net Worth            , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/don-imus-net-worth/
Name: Angie Harmon Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/angie-harmon-net-worth/
Name: Gene Hackman Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/gene-hackman-net-worth-2/
Name: Adam Brody Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/adam-brody-net-worth/
Name: Henry Cavill Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/henry-cavill-net-worth/
Name: Roddy Ricch Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-rappers/roddy-ricch-net-worth/
Name: Carlos Alazraqui Net Worth    , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/carlos-alazraqui-net-worth/
Name: Cardi B Net Worth             , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/models/cardi-b-net-worth/
Name: Summer Walker Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/summer-walker-net-worth/
Name: Ann Sothern Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/ann-sothern-net-worth/
Name: Martin May Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/martin-may-net-worth-2/
Name: Eric Shea Net Worth           , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/eric-shea-net-worth/
Name: Bun B Net Worth               , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-rappers/bun-b-net-worth/
Name: Julia Child Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-celebrity-chefs/julia-child-net-worth/
Name: Bill O'Reilly Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/authors/bill-oreilly-net-worth/
Name: Hayden Christensen Net Worth  , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/hayden-christensen-net-worth/
Name: Nicole Murphy Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/models/nicole-murphy-net-worth/
Name: Emma Kenney Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/emma-kenney-net-worth/
Name: Gabriele Corcos Net Worth     , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-celebrity-chefs/gabriele-corcos-net-worth/
Name: Christine Andreas Net Worth   , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/christine-andreas-net-worth/
Name: Donald Fagen Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/donald-fagen-net-worth/
Name: Rumer Willis Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/rumer-willis-net-worth/
Name: Helene Fischer Net Worth      , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/helene-fischer-net-worth/
Name: Anthony Clark Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/anthony-clark-net-worth/
Name: Big Al Anderson Net Worth     , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/rock-stars/big-al-anderson-net-worth/
Name: Safaree Samuels Net Worth     , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-rappers/safaee-samuels-net-worth/
Name: Jeremy Clyde Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/jeremy-clyde-net-worth/
Name: Lee Arenberg Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/lee-arenberg-net-worth/
Name: PnB Rock Net Worth            , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-rappers/pnb-rock-net-worth/
Name: Mike Love Net Worth           , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/rock-stars/mike-love-net-worth/
Name: Selma Blair Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/selma-blair-net-worth/
Name: Hugh Grant Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/hugh-grant-net-worth/
Name: Amanda Brooks Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/amanda-brooks-net-worth/
Name: Blake Lively Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/blake-lively-net-worth/
Name: Georgina Rodriguez Net Worth  , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/models/georgina-rodriguez-net-worth/
Name: Gal Gadot Net Worth           , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/models/gal-gadot-net-worth/
Name: Annie Lennox Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/annie-lennox-net-worth/
Name: Mariska Hargitay Net Worth    , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/mariska-hargitay-net-worth/
Name: Ram Dass Net Worth            , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/authors/ram-dass-net-worth/
Name: Erica Mena Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/models/erica-mena-net-worth/
Name: Marg Helgenberger Net Worth   , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/marg-helgenberger-net-worth/
Name: Al Michaels Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/al-michaels-net-worth/
Name: Malcolm-Jamal Warner Net Worth, Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/malcolm-jamal-warner-net-worth/
Name: Bruce Willis Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/bruce-willis-net-worth/
Name: Tami Roman Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/models/tami-roman-net-worth-2/
Name: Rian Johnson Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/directors/rian-johnson-net-worth/
Name: Allen Ludden Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/allen-ludden-net-worth/
Name: Christopher McQuarrie Net Worth, Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/directors/christopher-mcquarrie-net-worth/
Name: Robert Towne Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/directors/robert-towne-net-worth/
Name: Meg Ryan Net Worth            , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/meg-ryan-net-worth/
Name: Elizabeth Hurley Net Worth    , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/elizabeth-hurley-net-worth/
Name: Casey Affleck Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/casey-affleck-net-worth/
Name: Jonathan Goldsmith Net Worth  , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/jonathan-goldsmith-net-worth/
Name: Ed Bradley Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/authors/ed-bradley-net-worth/
Name: Keely Shaye Smith Net Worth   , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/keely-shaye-smith-net-worth/
Name: Linda Scott Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/linda-scott-net-worth/
Name: Paul Clark Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/paul-clark-net-worth/
Name: Gary Collins Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/gary-collins-net-worth/
Name: Jim Carrey Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/jim-carrey-net-worth/
Name: Eddie Murphy Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/eddie-murphy-net-worth/
Name: Aamir Khan Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/amir-khan-net-worth/
Name: Harrison Ford Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/harrison-ford-net-worth/
Name: Evelyn Lozada Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/models/evelyn-lozada-net-worth/
Name: Helen Reddy Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/helen-reddy-net-worth/
Name: Obie Trice Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-rappers/obie-trice-net-worth/
Name: Lori Harvey Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/models/lori-harvey-net-worth/
Name: Rebecca Black Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/rebecca-black-net-worth/
Name: Emile Hirsch Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/emile-hirsch-net-worth/
Name: Nick Cannon Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/nick-cannon-net-worth/
Name: Steve Miller Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/rock-stars/steve-miller-net-worth/
Name: Vivica A. Fox Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/vivica-fox-net-worth/
Name: Chuy Bravo Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-comedians/chuy-bravo-net-worth/
Name: Ezra Koenig Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/rock-stars/ezra-koenig-net-worth/
Name: Edward Snowden Net Worth      , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/authors/edward-snowden-net-worth/
Name: Walter Becker Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/rock-stars/walter-becker-net-worth/
Name: Kylie Jenner Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/models/kylie-jenner-net-worth/
Name: Millie Bobby Brown Net Worth  , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/millie-bobby-brown-net-worth/
Name: Leonardo DiCaprio Net Worth   , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/leonardo-dicaprio-net-worth/
Name: Billie Eilish Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/billie-eilish-net-worth/
Name: Leighton Meester Net Worth    , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/leighton-meester-net-worth/
Name: Carlene Carter Net Worth      , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/carlene-carter-net-worth/
Name: Richard Arnold Net Worth      , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/authors/richard-arnold-net-worth/
Name: Markie Post Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/markie-post-net-worth/
Name: Henry Rollins Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/henry-rollins-net-worth/
Name: Reba McEntire Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/reba-mcentire-net-worth/
Name: Ann Turner Cook Net Worth     , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/authors/ann-turner-cook-net-worth/
Name: Christopher Stanley Net Worth , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/christopher-stanley-net-worth/
Name: Debi Mazar Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/debi-mazar-net-worth/
Name: Kevin Kline Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/kevin-kline-net-worth/
Name: Charles Michael Davis Net Worth, Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/charles-michael-davis-net-worth/
Name: Frank Whaley Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/frank-whaley-net-worth/
Name: Elizabeth Banks Net Worth     , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/elizabeth-banks-net-worth/
Name: Len Wiseman Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/directors/len-wiseman-net-worth/
Name: Marie Fredriksson Net Worth   , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/marie-fredriksson-net-worth/
Name: Anil Kapoor Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/anil-kapoor-net-worth/
Name: Cleavon Little Net Worth      , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/cleavon-little-net-worth/
Name: Mel Brooks Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-comedians/mel-brooks-net-worth/
Name: Joe Jonas Net Worth           , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/joe-jonas-net-worth/
Name: Jim Cantore Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/jim-cantore-net-worth/
Name: David Ellefson Net Worth      , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/rock-stars/david-ellefson-net-worth/
Name: Sarah Snook Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/sarah-snook-net-worth/
Name: Lil Tecca Net Worth           , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-rappers/lil-tecca-net-worth/
Name: Michael O'Neill Net Worth     , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/michael-oneill-net-worth/
Name: Dave Stewart Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/rock-stars/dave-stewart-net-worth/
Name: Alan Jackson Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/rock-stars/alan-jackson-net-worth/
Name: Norah Jones Net Worth         , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/norah-jones-net-worth/
Name: Gwyneth Paltrow Net Worth     , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/gwyneth-paltrow-net-worth/
Name: Jimmy O. Yang Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-comedians/jimmy-o-yang-net-worth/
Name: Grace Potter Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/grace-potter-net-worth/
Name: Kali Uchis Net Worth          , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/kali-uchis-net-worth/
Name: Michael Lerner Net Worth      , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/michael-lerner-net-worth/
Name: Keren Woodward Net Worth      , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/keren-woodward-net-worth/
Name: Genie Francis Net Worth       , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/actors/genie-francis-net-worth/
Name: Katharine McPhee Net Worth    , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/singers/katharine-mcphee-net-worth/
Name: Eminem Net Worth              , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-rappers/eminem-net-worth/
Name: Jeana Keough Net Worth        , Url: https://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/jeana-keough-net-worth/
```